# How to make a heading with double lines on either side with tables

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've seen a lot of answers to this question using things like relative and absolute positioning, making line heights very small, etc. to achieve the effect I'm looking for. Since I'm trying to develop the same thing for emails, this is not as simple. I can achieve one line on either side of a header, but not two lines. Essentially it would look like -----My Header---- Here's my code for one line on either side

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="#" style="display: block; word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 100%; text-decoration: none; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="header" style="display: table; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; color: #000000; font-weight: 600; line-height: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.2px; font-size: 18px; width: 100%; max-width: 550px;">
                <span style="display: table-cell; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 10px;"><hr style="background-color: #000000; height: 3px;" /></span>MY HEADER
                <span style="display: table-cell; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;"><hr style="height: 3px; background-color: #000000;" /></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If that doesn't run, I might've made a typo. But either way, in gmail it renders just fine.

But how would one make it with two lines on either side? I'm at a complete loss for how to do this in email. Any advice would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result by using `absolute` positioning. The trick to `absolute` positioning is to set the parent element to `position: relative`
I additionally set the "My heading" in its own `span` with the `padding` to keep the horizontal bars at bay

EDIT: I removed the `display: table-cell` because it was unnecessary.

This should work

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="#" style="display: block; word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 100%; text-decoration: none; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="header" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; color: #000000; font-weight: 600; line-height: 130%; letter-spacing: 0.2px; font-size: 18px; width: 100%; max-width: 550px;position: relative;">
                <span style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle; position: absolute;top: 0;left: -10px;"><hr style="background-color: #000000; height: 3px;" /></span>
               <span style="padding: 0 25px;"> MY HEADER</span>
                <span style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle; position: absolute;top: 0;right: -10px;"><hr style="height: 3px; background-color: #000000;" /></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This only works on iOS. Gmail, Outlook, Samsung, etc. etc. show a hr, linebreak, header, linebreak, hr.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a table with three columns. You can't simply change things with `display` (so, don't even try to use a span with padding - spans are inline, not block), nor is positioning widely supported.

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 20px">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><hr style="background-color: #000000; height: 3px;min-width:20px" /></td>
                    <td width="60%"><p style="padding: 0 25px;text-align: center;">MY&nbsp;HEADER</p></td>
                    <td width="20%"><hr style="background-color: #000000; height: 3px;min-width:20px" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```